# Number of fridays between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, select, date

How do I find the number of fridays between two dates(including both the dates) using a select statement in oracle sql?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will do it:

```
select ((next_day(date2-7,'FRI')-next_day(date-1,'FRI'))/7)+1 as num_fridays
from data
```

Perhaps best if I break that down.  The NEXT_DAY function returns the next day that is a (Friday in this case) **after** the date.

So to find the first Friday after d1 would be:

```
next_day( d1, 'FRI')
```

But if d1 is a Friday that would return the following Friday, so we adjust:

```
next_day( d1-1, 'FRI')
```

Similarly to find the last Friday up to and including d2 we do:

```
next_day( d1-7, 'FRI')
```

Subtracting the 2 gives a number of days: 0 if they are the same date, 7 if they a re a week apart and so on:

```
next_day( d1-7, 'FRI') - next_day( d1-1, 'FRI')
```

Convert to weeks:

```
(next_day( d1-7, 'FRI') - next_day( d1-1, 'FRI')) / 7
```

Finally, if they are the same date we get 0, but really there is 1 Friday, and so on so we add one:

```
((next_day( d1-7, 'FRI') - next_day( d1-1, 'FRI')) / 7) + 1
```

Comment: +1 , but note that next_day() function depends on NLS parameters and better use well-known friday date to get string constant instead of 'FRI' string: to_char(to_date('20110211', 'yyyymmdd'), 'day')

Comment: Awesome solution! I was able to play around and get much done with it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

I have to throw in my two cents for using a calendar table. (It's a compulsion.)

```
select count(*) as num_fridays
from calendar
where day_of_week = 'Fri'
  and cal_date between '2011-01-01' and '2011-02-17';

num_fridays
-----------
6
```

Dead simple to understand. Takes advantage of indexes.

Maybe I should start a 12-step group. Calendar Table Anonymous.

Comment: +1 for getting a reminder (once again) for how useful such a calender table would be. If only such a table were installed by default.

Comment: Indeed. The problem seems to be that people see what we have, and that blinds us to what we need.

Answer (score 2):

See:

[Why should I consider using an auxiliary calendar table?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html)

The article's code is specifically for SQL Server but the techniques are portable to most SQL platforms.

With a Calendar table in place your query could be as simple as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS friday_tally
  FROM YourTable AS T1
       INNER JOIN Calendar AS C1
          ON C1.dt BETWEEN T1.start_date AND T1.end_date
 WHERE C1.day_name = 'Friday'; -- could be a numeric code
```

Comment: I promise to always upvote a calendar table. I promise to always upvote a calendar table. I promise to always upvote a calendar table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case when trim(to_char(to_date('2009-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')+rownum,'Day')) = 'Friday' then 1 else 0 end) number_of_fridays
from dual
connect by level <= to_date('&end_date','YYYY-MM-DD') - to_date('&start_date','YYYY-MM-DD')+1;
```

Original source - http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3987357&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_WORKINGS_DAYS  
(V_START_DATE IN DATE, V_END_DATE IN DATE)

RETURN NUMBER IS
DAY_COUNT NUMBER := 0;
CURR_DATE DATE;

BEGIN -- loop through and update
CURR_DATE := V_START_DATE;
WHILE CURR_DATE <= V_END_DATE
LOOP
    IF TO_CHAR(CURR_DATE,'DY') NOT IN ('SAT','SUN') -- Change this bit to ignore all but Fridays
        THEN DAY_COUNT := DAY_COUNT + 1;
    END IF;
    CURR_DATE := CURR_DATE + 1;
END LOOP;

    RETURN DAY_COUNT;
END F_WORKINGS_DAYS;
```

/

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (NEXT_DAY('31-MAY-2012','SUN')
-NEXT_DAY('04-MAR-2012','SUN'))/7 FROM DUAL
```

Comment: The question asked for Fridays, and the accepted answer more than covers the same ground using NEXT_DAY

Answer (score -1):

select ((DATEDIFF(dd,@a,@b)) + DATEPART(dw,(@a-6)))/7