# Count the no of Fridays (or any) between two specific dates?

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

Is there any way in php can we count the no of Fridays (or any other day specified) between two set of dates included ?
I was doing it through sql like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967808/number-of-fridays-between-two-dates?rq=1) now i want to implement directly in php, s i have googled and found only no of days and weeks all other but not for week of days.

Comment: There is, yes. Did you try anything?

Comment: check the first date (is it sunday or ..) you have 7 days ... you do the math

Comment: @oGeez s i googled it . and also tried to implement like (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967808/number-of-fridays-between-two-dates) through sql but y to go to sql and do it

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653891/how-to-find-number-of-mondays-or-tuesdays-between-two-dates

Answer (score 6):

You can get the count number of specific day, between date range, **without looping over all days**.
I have modified [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3814569/67332).

**Use:**

```php
echo dayCount('2013-11-15', '2013-11-22', 5); # 2x Friday
echo dayCount('2013-11-15', '2013-11-22', 1); # 1x Monday
```

**Function:**

```php
function dayCount($from, $to, $day = 5) {
    $from = new DateTime($from);
    $to   = new DateTime($to);

    $wF = $from->format('w');
    $wT = $to->format('w');
    if ($wF < $wT)       $isExtraDay = $day >= $wF && $day <= $wT;
    else if ($wF == $wT) $isExtraDay = $wF == $day;
    else                 $isExtraDay = $day >= $wF || $day <= $wT;

    return floor($from->diff($to)->days / 7) + $isExtraDay;
}
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/69797)**

Comment: I had added array of the days name, so you can call the function with the name of the day as the PHP date functions will help getting the name.

Comment: Just pay attention that the third parameter is (w - A numeric representation of the day (0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday))

Answer (score 1):

First, You can get the current month thursdays (example).

```
$registered = strtotime(date('d/m/Y'));
$lastday = strtotime(date('t/m/Y'));
$curMonth = date("m");
for ($i=1; $i < 15; $i++){
    $week = $i*7; 
    if (date("m",strtotime("next thursday - 42 days + $week days")) == $curMonth){
            $monthArr[] = date("d",strtotime("next thursday - 42 days + $week days"));
    }
}
```

Then you will find the thursdays from current date to end of the date of month.

```
foreach($monthArr as $moAr) {
    if(date("d") <= $moAr) {
        $get[] = $moAr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the given code:

```
<?php
$no = 0;
$start = new DateTime('2013-11-11');
$end   = new DateTime('2013-11-23');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt)
{
    if ($dt->format('N') == 5)
    {
        $no++;
    }
}
echo $no;
```

where 5 in `$dt->format('N') == 5` denotes the 5th day in the week ie, friday.

Comment: IMO looping over all days is just overkill. Plus, this example ignores last date, so for `2013-11-15` - `2013-11-22` range it will only return one friday, where there are 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function using recursion.

```
    function dayCount($day, $startDate, $endDate, $counter){
      if($startDate >= $endDate){
        return $counter;
      }else{
        return dayCount($day, strtotime("next ".$day, $startDate), $endDate, ++$counter);
     }
   }

echo dayCount("Friday", strtotime("2019-03-01"), strtotime("2019-03-31"), 0); exit();
```

the Output is 5